# Apache-karaf 4.0.4 container getting Killed without any error messages

Tags: docker, apache-karaf

Run command is : exec ./karaf debug

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005

```
     __ __                  ____
    / //_/____ __________ _/ __/
   / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_
  / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/
 /_/ |_|\__,_/_/   \__,_/_/
```

Apache Karaf (4.0.4)

Hit '' for a list of available commands

and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.

Hit '' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown Karaf.

karaf@root()> 'org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.adapter.LogEventAdapter$1@a7e23e9' is removed as a

LogListener, since it threw an exception.

Killed

exited with code 137

Answer (score 0):

137 means out of memory. Increase the memory for the container. This is seldom since karaf uses only a small amount of memory.